# How do I delete a Spotify radio station?

Tags: windows-7, spotify

I found a solution that states to do the following:

- Search your computer for Spotify
- Right Click > Open File Location
- Click Users > some#-user > Local Storage > LocalStorage
- Delete `sp_radio_0.localstorage`

But there's no such thing as `Local Storage` nor `LocalStorage`. And this file `sp_radio_0.localstorage` doesn't appear to exist.  Is there another way to delete a station, or am I missing something here?

**EDIT**

I'll show you what I see:

- I see this

[image]

- And as you see, no hidden folders

[image]

Comment: have you enabled 'show hidden folders' ?

Comment: @Shakehar yes i did, that option is always enabled on my pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this method myself, and while I honestly don't understand why `Local Storage` and it's Subdirectories aren't being listed in your system, I was able to find the file and delete it. However, I'm sad to report that the method itself no longer works due to the fact that Spotify now pulls your Stations from it's cloud player and applications.

The reasoning behind Spotify decision to deny users the ability to delete stations is beyond me.